# Animate Child View in ExpandableList

Tags: android, animation, expandablelistview

I only have 1 child view for each group view, which is inflated from a layout .xml file. I wish to animate the child view so that when the child item is displayed, the list item below it slides down. I tries this with a number of animations, but the isse is that the height/ width of the child view is first made visible and then the view animates within that space. However, I want a child view to show between 2 list views by making the following group view slide down to make way for the chile view.

For exanple, I tried the following. The animation does happens, but not as I have described above. I have added the following to the getChildView(), just before I return the child view:

```
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyExpandableList.this,
                                                   R.anim.translate);
    v.setAnimation(anim);
```

Here's is my translate.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:fromYDelta="-50%p" 
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

Thanks for your help.

Ani.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to animate all child views below the currently added child view also.
Add all the `Aniamtions` to an `AnimationSet` and start the set.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I have a maximum of 1 child view, per group view. So, adding the animation to all the child views is not possible.

Comment: animate all the groupviews below the currently adding view. That should animate as u need.

Comment: I don't want to animate the group view. I just want to animate 1 child view of every group view.

Comment: Without animating the groupviews how do you expect the whole thing to appear sliding. All the views below the current added(whichever it is in the list) should be in the animation.

Comment: That's the point! I don't want the whole screen to slide. I just want my child view to appear as sliding - which should appear as though it is pushing the next view group down. On collapsing the child view the reverse should happen.

Comment: You should understand how animations take place in android for that. While animating the view is set invisible and a bitmap of the view is moved on the screen instead of the view. in the end the view is set to visible again and bitmap destroyed. So there is no way for it to show like a new view pushing other groups as they are already pushed down as soon as u added the view. So u need to add the following groups as well to the animations.